# What is CompletableFuture's equivalent of flatMap?

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I have this weird type `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<byte[]>>` but i want `CompletableFuture<byte[]>`. Is this possible?

```
public Future<byte[]> convert(byte[] htmlBytes) {
    PhantomPdfMessage htmlMessage = new PhantomPdfMessage();
    htmlMessage.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
    htmlMessage.setTimestamp(new Date());
    htmlMessage.setEncodedContent(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(htmlBytes));

    CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<byte[]>> thenApply = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::getPhantom, threadPool).thenApply(
        worker -> worker.convert(htmlMessage).thenApply(
            pdfMessage -> Base64.getDecoder().decode(pdfMessage.getEncodedContent())
        )
    );

}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's a [bug](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/rev/94e2be8fe284) in its documentation, but the [`CompletableFuture#thenCompose`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-) family of methods is the equivalent of a `flatMap`. Its declaration should also give you some clues

```
public <U> CompletableFuture<U> thenCompose(Function<? super T,? extends CompletionStage<U>> fn)
```

`thenCompose` takes the result of the receiver `CompletableFuture` (call it **1**) and passes it to the `Function` you provide, which must return its own `CompletableFuture` (call it **2**). The `CompletableFuture` (call it **3**) returned by `thenCompose` will be completed when **2** completes.

In your example

```
CompletableFuture<Worker> one = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::getPhantom, threadPool);
CompletableFuture<PdfMessage /* whatever */> two = one.thenCompose(worker -> worker.convert(htmlMessage));
CompletableFuture<byte[]> result = two.thenApply(pdfMessage -> Base64.getDecoder().decode(pdfMessage.getEncodedContent()));
```